# Probability of certain events

Tags: probability

The probability of a drought is $3\%$, the probability of crop loss due to sever cold is $2 \%$ and the probability of both is $1.5\%$.

Now I'm looking for the probability of;

$1$.) Drought or crop loss due to severe cold i.e. $P(A \mbox{ or } B) = P(A)+P(B) = 5\%$?

$2$.) Neither a drought nor a cold spell i.e. $1-P(A\mbox{ or }B) = 0.95$?

$3$.) No drought, not sure how to do this one, maybe $1-P(A) = 0.97$?

Answer (score 1):

1.) $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$, which, in this case, is $3\% + 2\% - 1.5\% = 3.5\%$.

This is the case because to find the probability that one event or the other happens, one counts first the probability that $A$ occurs, then the probability that $B$ occurs. However, this accounts twice for the possibility that both $A$ and $B$ occur, so the probability that both occur is then subtracted from the total to bring it to the correct value.

2.) This will be $1 - P(A \cup B)$, which will be $96.5\%$.

3.) Yes, this will just be $1 - P(A)$, or $97\%$.